# Verb for intentionally misinterpreting a written or spoken statement

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, verbs

I'm looking for an verb that could be used to describe the act of intentionally misinterpreting a written or spoken statement. I'm not seeking the word "mondegreen."

HELLO Im sorry to put this here, but I don't have enough points that allow me to provide an answer in the responses below.

Is the word, Malign?

MALIGN: transitive verb. : to utter injuriously misleading or false reports about : speak evil of. Her supporters say that she has been unfairly maligned in the press.

Hi Keith, That's a creative way to post your answer, and I'll respond in kind: It's not malign, though the intent may be malignant.

Comment: You have to be more specific than "intentionally".

Comment: Is it done maliciously or as a joke? My husband pretends to misunderstand what I say all the time... but he does it to tease me. Someone else may do it intentionally to spin what's being said in their favor.

Comment: I heard the word used to describe the tactics of a radio talk-show host who would frequently distort the questions or comments of call-in listeners in order to give answers that fit his agenda. I suppose it is a rhetorical device.

Answer (score 2):

**[slant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slant)**

> [with object] (often as adjective slanted) Present or view (information) from a particular angle, especially in a biased or unfair way:
>
> *I agree that this is ridiculously politically slanted in one direction*

or

**[distort](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/distort)**

> Give a misleading or false account or impression of:
>
> *Many investors now distrust pension accounting because it distorts reported earnings.*

or

figurative use of **[contort](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contort)**

> Twist or bend out of the normal shape:
>
> figurative: *a contorted version of the truth*

All of this imply (malicious) intention.

Answer (score 2):

> misconstrue

This is an act of distorting or misrepresenting some other speech or text.

> Don't misconstrue what I am saying, you know that's not what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

*Misrepresent*: "to describe (someone or something) in a false way especially in order to deceive someone : to give someone a false idea about (something or someone)" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misrepresent).

Comment: Misrepresent is very close,  but I'm familiar with it. This was a verb that I hadn't heard before, and it seemed especially appropriate for radio talk-show communication.

Comment: Well, if you hadn't heard it before, and you heard in the context of a radio talk show, then yes, you might think that. ;-)

Comment: I heard it used by a critic discussing the tactics of conservative radio talk-show hosts.

Answer (score 2):

**spin**

A word (verb or noun) commonly used in that context (talk radio) to describe spinning a story to be more favorable to its target audience (that's key), whether the spin is negative or positive.

Whereas the general definition of *spin* (OL) is more likely to refer to presenting the subject itself more favorably:

> give (a news story or other information) a particular interpretation, especially a favorable one.

For many online examples, search *talk radio spin, no spin radio, truth or spin,* etc.

See also: *skew* (as in *Don't skew what I said.*)

Comment: The word I'm seeking shares aspects with several of the answers, but quite specifically means intentionally mishearing what someone says. In Waugh's Brideshead revisited, Edward "Ned" Ryder, the father of Charles Ryder, the novel's protagonist, uses this technique with his son and his son's friends. He does it for his own amusement, but it baffles Charles's companions.

Comment: @Zan700 - You should put that in your question, the context, but I'm not familiar with it. I thought your context was *talk radio* from other comments; I'll delete this later.

Answer (score 1):

To **misread** is to "judge or interpret (a situation or a person's manner or behavior) incorrectly." and can be applied equally to a written or spoken statement. It is, however, neutral with respect to intent, and to fit your question would be used as **willfully misread**.

I'm pretty sure you're not using "interpret" in the sense of converting from one language to another. If you are, I believe **willfully mistranslate** would be used, since "misinterpret" is already widely used in the sense of misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about someone's intentionally misinterpreting in a discussion or debate about ideas, there are specific terms. One common tactic to use a "Straw Man" argument. That's accurate when your opponent answers a question you didn't ask with the intention to dissemble. There's also using "Socratic irony," a trick to bait an opponent to trip him/her up. But neither term is a verb.

Hmmm ... these don't look as good in writing as they did in my head. The problem I'm having is that you're using a verb with an adverb yourself. I realize, though, you can't use a synonym because then you'd be answering your own question.

Comment: You see "straw man" used [as a verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) these days too (especially "strawmanning"), although probably not in many dictionaries. It's definitely in the right area.

Comment: Certainly this is a verb that has gained currency in Internet times, where we are all perpetually arguing. Look up "steelmanning".

Answer (score 1):

I'll give one more suggestion (but everybody else is correct that you need to give a specific example of your case): it's common for people to be **passive-aggressive**.  You can look up that phrase in any dictionary.  It is absolutely a kind of "intentional misinterpretation".